# TBLPROPERTIES doesn't propagate to table partitions

Tags: hive, hiveql, partition

I create a table in hive and set TBLPROPERTIES.
The problem is that when I add partitions - these TBLPROPERTIES doesn't propagate to them. That is the set TBLPROPERTIES doesn't exist in the partitions.

Any idea what might help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround would be to use "SERDEPROPERTIES". 
Apparently those do propagate to the partitions and you can read them from your serde implementation